# Possible to limit the countries an iOS application is released to?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to limit the countries an iOS application is released to? Is it possible to limit a version to a certain country?

If so, where could I find more information. I attempted searching the documentation but was unable to locate decisive information regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, you can control which App Stores you app is sold in. This can be done in iTunes Connect.

First, choose your app from your App Dashboard. Next, look for "Rights and Pricing" in the top right corner.

[image: Rights and Pricing in iTunes Connect]

Next, scroll down. You will see a link to sell in specific countries.

[image: Selecting specific countries for sale]

After clicking on that link, you will be able to select which stores your app is for sale in.

[image: The expanded list of possible stores]

Comment: Does altering this data change the available countries instantly?

Comment: Propagation probably takes time, as all changes do.

Comment: Is it possible to limit the regions for each version of the app differently?

Comment: @dan did you find an answer for that?

Comment: @Yossi sorry I guess not

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: // Does altering this data change the available countries instantly? //
Any answer for this?

Comment: It probably takes several (up to 24) hours to propogate across servers.

Answer (score 40):

In [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/) as of March 2021

## 1. Click your app dropdown

[image]

## 2. Click **Pricing and Availability**,

Under Availability click **EDIT**

[image]

---

you'll see

[image]

Comment: I did that, but what happen the previous version was discontinued from all country and new version available only in selected country

Comment: What is your objective and expectation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set the stores it will be available in when you upload. It's under one of the tabs, where you set the price.

Comment: Do you know if we could limit a version to a country? (For example: v1.0 global release v1.1 for USA)

Comment: No, I don't think it is possible to limit a version, just the entire app itself.

Answer (score 0):

> You can select the territories where you want your app to be available
> on the App Store.
>
> By default, all countries or regions are selected, but you can
> deselect territories where you don’t want your app for sale.
>
> Source: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devcdda55918