# How do I launch my iOS iPhone app only in China?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, launching-application

I am developing an iOS app that I only want to be available in China. I know that the Apple app store has country specific stores. Is there a country selector in Xcode or is there some sort of checkbox on developer.apple.com? I've searched high and low, and no resources or guides address this specific issue. Can someone enlighten me on this process? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to limit the countries an iOS application is released to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694280/possible-to-limit-the-countries-an-ios-application-is-released-to)

Answer (score 2):

You can select the specific stores in iTunes connect under pricing menu:
[image]

[image]

[image]