# How much time does it take after updating country availability in app store

Tags: app-store

Updated the app in beta channel, currently USA only, to be available in Italy as well, using the instructions at [Possible to limit the countries an iOS application is released to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694280/possible-to-limit-the-countries-an-ios-application-is-released-to)

How much time it takes the app to be visible in the newly updated country? How would I know if/when the change was effective?

Comment: You should add an answer that tells us how long it took for your app to be available. 5 years later we still have no idea if this takes 30 minutes or 3 weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there isn't any specific time constraint limit, set/committed by Apple for this (or any other) process. The time they take to process you update, depends upon rush/queue of application submission and updates on store.

There is a small window of hope, provided by Apple, if you've an emergency or urgency to update your app (country list) on store.

Send a request to Apple using your developer account and contact CSR team. They will definitely listen you and consider your request.

I hope this may help you...

Comment: Do we need to release the new version to add 2-3 countries in availability?