# Need information about storefront in ios developer

Tags: ios, iosdeployment

i have published my ios app in appstore and app is still in review today i got email from apple that your app has been rejected. This is the issue they listed down below but i dont understand what is the issue.

We found that your app is not appropriate for the World storefront because it is a custom app designed specifically for Kulsum International Hospital, whose users are in Pakistan.

At this time, Pakistan is not part of the Volume Purchase Program.

Please revise your app to set the storefront to Pakistan.

can anyone help to get rid of this issue please. Thanks

Comment: This means your app should be geographically limited to Pakistan as the only users who can use it are living in Pakistan

Comment: apple send me this - Please revise your app to set the storefront to Pakistan, but from where i can change it?

Answer (score 0):

The message clearly states that you need to limit your app to Pakistan's storefront.

To do so : Go to the `Pricing` tab of your app and you will find a link to select the stores where to publish your app.

More details on this answer : [Limit App to specific countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694280/possible-to-limit-the-countries-an-ios-application-is-released-to)

On the other hand and if you app should not be restricted to Pakistan, you can reply to the rejection with proofs that the users might come from abroad.